# Ошибка в bash скрипте

Tags: linux, bash

В папке есть определённые файлы, нужно создать папку для каждого, имя которой будет именем файла с добавлением "_". После создания папки - перенос её в другое место и копирование в неё исходного файла.

```
#мой скрипт

#!/bin/bash
   for file in `find /root/Desktop/testtest/ -type f -name "*.txt"`; do
       mkdir $dir1 ${file}_
       mv "$dir1" /root/Desktop/testingScript
       cp "$file" "$dir1"
   done
```

Он прекрасно выполняет создание папки, но дальнейшие операции - нет (папки не переносит, файлы в них не копирует). Помогите найти ошибку и подскажите, что нужно добавить, чтоб скрипт смотрел имя файла до его расширения (".txt" в данном примере) и называл папку именем без расширения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно, так?

```
for file in `find /root/Desktop/testtest/ -type f -name "*.txt"`; do
    filename=`basename "$file"`
    dir1="/root/Desktop/testingScript/${filename%.*}_"
    mkdir -p "$dir1"
    cp "$file" "$dir1"
done
```

Comment: Всё работает, большое спасибо.